# Why fragment still keep it memory address when the fragment is destroyed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment-lifecycle

I try to log all of fragment life-cycle inside viewpager which using **StateFragmentAdapter**.Fragment **A** move to fragment **C** and it logged that fragment **A** is **onDestroy** and **onDestroyView**.but when i return to fragment **A**,the memory addresss of that fragment same as the destroyed fragment.So i wonder that is that it create a new fragment on the same addresss or it's still that fragment inside that addresss?

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: @akshay_shahane i will update my question

Comment: how exactly are you getting the memory address btw?

Comment: @Kushan i just print the fragment.so just like other object it print the memory address right?

Comment: no, that it not the memory address, java does not allow access to memory address. It is default toString() output and is pretty much useless for anyone. Your fragment will always get re created from scratch after a call to onDestroy

Comment: what you are seeing is classname@hexstring_of_hashcode_of_object

Comment: @Kushan but why the result of fragment.toString() is always the same String even when the fragment is destroyed and another fragment is created?

Comment: If two Objects are equal, according to the the equals(Object) method, then hashCode() method must produce the same Integer on each of the two Objects. each fragment which is recreated is basically the exact same object so you get the exact same value of hashcode and thus you get the exact same output.

Comment: @Kushan thank you for all of this knowledge!!! upvoted all!!!